# activerecord can't recognize the correct class when inside folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, module

I have the current structure

```
Module1
  Interactions
  User

Module2
  Interactions
  Person
  User < Person
```

when I load the user from module1, with `Module1::User.first`, the User is loaded correctly but when I try load the user from module2 (`Module2::Person.first`) I got `Unable to autoload constant User, expected module1/user.rb to define it`. How can I get this to work?

Edit: `Person` has a column `type`, with the value "User". STI

Comment: your example doesn't make sense.  You're calling Person.first yet your error is in reference to a user class

Comment: Person has a column `type`, which references to `User`. Single table inheritance

Comment: Might be worth including your exact class definitions. Are you defining the classes with, for example `class Module2::Person < Module2::User` and `class Module2::User`?

Comment: No, I'm doing like `module Module1 class User end end`, so, ended up like `class User < Module2::User`

Comment: would help if you showed your module and class definitions within your question, rather than just the structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved using [Ignorable](https://github.com/nthj/ignorable) gem. Didn't need the STI in this case, is a legacy database